# Google Spreadsheet SQL subquery "where not in"

Tags: google-sheets

I'm attempting to perform the following SQL command concept, but with two sheets in the same google spreadsheet document:

```
select * from table1
where column1 not in (select column1 from table2)
```

How do I achieve the same subquery concept using Google Spreasheet SQL?

**Update**

Here is a conceptual example of what I'd like to accomplish: I have a list of requirements on one sheet, and a requirement accomplishment log on another sheet. The log is simply the person's name and the name of the requirement (matching the other sheet). I'd like to see a report on all the requirements that do not exist in the requirement accomplishment log.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your comment makes no sense. My question is quite clear, and I do not "quote what does not work"... (Are you referring to an example of TSQL that I gave?) Do you want me to give you an example scenario, or was the purpose of your comment only to critique the question?

Comment: 1 month later. Did you manage to find an answer? I'd love to know as well! :P

Comment: None yet. I'd settle for a kludge solution to achieve the same effect, if anyone has one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this and with filtering to select "Not accomplished":

[image: WA59459 example]

The formula in C2 (copied down) is:

```
=if(not(iserror(vlookup(B2,Sheet2!B:B,1,0))),"","Not accomplished")
```

Comment: I hadn't seen your suggestion. While I'm not sure this does answer this specific much broader SQL question (`where not in`) it sure works for his example there, which is precisely what I wanted to do as well!